# Flowplayer - Warning: Division by zero

Tags: plugins

I am facing a weird issue on my wordpress site:

```
http://konosubaepisodes.com
```

The site shows the following warning:

> Warning: Division by zero in
>   /home/konosuba/public_html/wp-content/plugins/fv-wordpress-flowplayer/models/flowplayer-frontend.php
>   on line 419

Line 419 is `$ratio = round($height / $width, 4);`

None of my videos have a defined width of 0.

The error does not appear on pages where the player is hosted.

If I view the source of the main page, I can see the tons of unrelated code that may be generated because of the error!

I did try to uninstall and then reinstall the plugin ( FV Player ), but that didn`t help.

Any ideas?

not sure if this is the right code where width is defined but it seems so:

```
/* *  Set common variables  */
$width = ( isset($this->conf['width']) && (!empty($this->conf['width'])) && intval($this->conf['width']) > 0 ) ? $this->conf['width'] : 320;
$height = ( isset($this->conf['height']) && (!empty($this->conf['height'])) && intval($this->conf['height']) > 0 ) ? $this->conf['height'] : 240;
if (isset($this->aCurArgs['width']) && !empty($this->aCurArgs['width']))
    $width = trim($this->aCurArgs['width']);
if (isset($this->aCurArgs['height']) && !empty($this->aCurArgs['height']))
    $height = trim($this->aCurArgs['height']);
$src1 = ( isset($this->aCurArgs['src1']) && !empty($this->aCurArgs['src1']) ) ? trim($this->aCurArgs['src1']) : false;
$src2 = ( isset($this->aCurArgs['src2']) && !empty($this->aCurArgs['src2']) ) ? trim($this->aCurArgs['src2']) : false;
```

@David:  it seems like it is pulling the code from the latest post ( season 2 episode 6) Here is what it is pulling for example and inserting it.

```
<table width="620"> <tbody> <tr> <td><strong><img data-attachment-id="72" data-permalink="http://konosubaepisodes.com/69-revision-v1/" data-orig-file="" data-orig-size="" data-comments-opened="0" data-image-meta="[]" data-image-title="Konosuba 2 Episode 6" data-image-description="&lt;h2 align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;Episode 6&lt;/h2&gt; &lt;p&gt;[tabs]&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;[tab title=&quot;FV Player&quot;]&lt;br /&gt; [fvplayer src=&quot;http://mp4watch.tv/media/konosuba/konosuba_s2e6.mp4&quot; width=&quot;848&quot; height=&quot;480&quot;]&lt;br /&gt; [/tab] &lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;[tab title=&quot;Gvideo Player&quot;]&lt;br /&gt; [gvideojs gdid=&quot;0B5i7u5TAodOFb0FVc05qOFRiSW8&quot;]&lt;br /&gt; [/tab] &lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;[tab title=&quot;Smart Player&quot;]&lt;br /&gt; [videojs mp4=&quot;http://mp4watch.tv/media/konosuba/konosuba_s2e6.mp4&quot;]&lt;br /&gt; [/tab] &lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;[tab title=&quot;Mp4upload Player&quot;]&lt;br /&gt; &lt;iframe src=&quot;http://www.mp4upload.com/embed-ra29qn8hkxuj.html&quot; width=&quot;848&quot; height=&quot;480&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; marginwidth=&quot;0&quot; marginheight=&quot;0&quot; scrolling=&quot;NO&quot; allowfullscreen=&quot;allowfullscreen&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;br /&gt; [/tab] &lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;[/tabs]&lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: and the default video width is defined on fv player settings.

Comment: can you add the code where $height and $with are defined?

Comment: @David Lee: I hope I added the right code!

Comment: I dont think its related to the division by zero, you will need to debug where that content is being called and outputted, seems like the actual content of the post?

Comment: yes, but this is weird and it appeared along the division by zero error.

Comment: check where exactly its outputting and what function you have in that place in your file, if its in the `<header>` it could be `wp_head()` check the functions that are being executed for that filter, that way you can track from where is coming and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your code can be improved but using what you have try this:

```
/* *  Set common variables  */
$width = ( isset($this->conf['width']) && (!empty($this->conf['width'])) && intval($this->conf['width']) > 0 ) ? $this->conf['width'] : 320;
$height = ( isset($this->conf['height']) && (!empty($this->conf['height'])) && intval($this->conf['height']) > 0 ) ? $this->conf['height'] : 240;

if (isset($this->aCurArgs['width']) && !empty($this->aCurArgs['width'])&& intval($this->aCurArgs['width']) > 0)
    $width = trim($this->aCurArgs['width']);
if (isset($this->aCurArgs['height']) && !empty($this->aCurArgs['height']) && intval($this->aCurArgs['height']) > 0)
    $height = trim($this->aCurArgs['height']);

$src1 = ( isset($this->aCurArgs['src1']) && !empty($this->aCurArgs['src1']) ) ? trim($this->aCurArgs['src1']) : false;
$src2 = ( isset($this->aCurArgs['src2']) && !empty($this->aCurArgs['src2']) ) ? trim($this->aCurArgs['src2']) : false;
```

i added the check for 0 to the two `IF`.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same, you beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks David. The error doesn`t appear anymore on the front page. However, if you check the source code of the front page. I still see the unwanted code within the page.

Comment: can you add that unwanted code? i think that it might not be related to the division by zero.

Comment: @David: added the code